# Remove hidden files from directory list in Racket

Tags: file, directory, racket

In Racket, I can get a list of all files in the current directory with the `directory-list` function:

```
> (directory-list)
'(#<path:.git>
  #<path:.gitignore>
  #<path:README>)
```

However, if I run `ls` on the command line, it defaults to hiding all files starting with a `.`

```
$ ls
README
```

Is there any way to filter the result of `directory-list` to show only files that are not hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `file/glob` library ignores dotfiles by default. You can override that behavior with a keyword argument.

```
$ ls
README
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v7.6.0.9.
> (require file/glob)
> (glob "*")
'(#<path:/tmp/dir/README>)
> (glob "*" #:capture-dotfiles? #t)
'(#<path:/tmp/dir/.git> #<path:/tmp/dir/.gitignore> #<path:/tmp/dir/README>)
```

EDIT: If you're only searching the current directory, you can get relative paths using `find-relative-path`:

```
> (map (lambda (x) (find-relative-path (current-directory) x)) (glob "*"))
'(#<path:.git> #<path:.gitignore> #<path:README>)
```